# javascript read php function

Tags: php, javascript

How to make this working. javascript should read the php value by return and disply it.

thank you,

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var _date = "<?= 

  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->load( 'http://web.com/public.xml' );
  $elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "data" );

  $dates = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "i_data" );
  $_date = $dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
  return $_date;

 ?>";

alert(_date)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: do you mean echo, right?

Comment: would that php function not be stored elsewhere and accessed by ajax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to organize it differently:

```
<?php
  function giveDate(){
    $xml = new DOMDocument(); 
    $xml->load( 'http://web.com/public.xml' ); 
    $elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "data" ); 

    $dates = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "i_data" ); 
    $_date = $dates->item(0)->nodeValue; 
    return $_date; 
  }
?>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var _date = '<?=giveDate()?>';
  alert(_date) 
</script>
```

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as final.

Answer (score 4):

Use `<?php` not `<?=`

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var _date = "<?php 

  $xml = new DOMDocument();
  $xml->load( 'http://web.com/public.xml' );
  $elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "data" );

  $dates = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "i_data" );
  $_date = $dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
  echo $_date; //<<-- echo, NOT return

 ?>";

alert(_date)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `echo` not `return`. PHP is server-side, so it needs to output the information to the page, not "return" it to the client. `return` should be used in function calls.

Also, use the long PHP tags (`<?php ... ?>`) to be safe.

---

Alternate method using return:

```
<script>
  var _date = "<?php
    function getDate(){
      $xml = new DOMDocument();
      $xml->load( 'http://web.com/public.xml' );
      $elements = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "data" );

      $dates = $xml->getElementsByTagName( "i_data" );
      $_date = $dates->item(0)->nodeValue;
      return $_date;
    }
    echo getDate();
  ?>";
  alert(_date);
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to generate VALID javascript for this to work. If that date value you're getting out of XML is a string, you'll have to surround it with quotes. The simplest method of ensuring you get valid javascript out of PHP is by using json-encode:

```
var _date = <?php ... xml stuff here ...; echo json_encode($_date); ?>;
```

Comment: `json_encode`?? when all you need is a string? i dont think that is the best approach -- **and** that does not solve the problem at all!

Comment: Yes, it is. json-encode guarantees that you end up with valid javascript, regardless of the content of what you're echoing. I agree it's overkill for what should be a simple date string, but it's an easy thing to get into the habit of doing and makes your life so much easier down the road.  How does this not solve the problem?

Comment: you did not show the OP why what he/she did is not working. I mean, right your answer is not `wrong` per se, but lacking a little context,